# Access public class method parameter from Private class in C#

Tags: c#

When I try to access the `Arch` parameter I am passing in a public `Runner()` function from a private `RunTest()` function, I get the following error:

> Arch does not exist in the current context

Please help me to fix this.

```
public void Runner(string Arch = "x64")
{
}

private TestResult RunTest(TCDetailInfo tcDetailInfo)
{
    if Arch = "x64"
        x = y + 2;
}
```

Comment: Read up on *"scope"*. A variable can be scoped to a class or to a method, or even a block of code within a method. Method parameters are always scoped to the methods they are declared to be part of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a variable outside the Runner method and assign the value of Arch to it. Later, you can access it in other methods.

```
public class YourClass
{
     private string _arch;
     public void Runner(string arch = "x64")
     {
          //Do you stuff to arch
          //Assign a value to the private variable _arch declared above the Runner method
          _arch = arch;
     }

     private TestResult RunTest(TCDetailInfo tcDetailInfo)
     {
          //Here, you can access the value of private variable _arch
          if (_arch == "x64")
          {
              x=y+2;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks saratcsss that worked. Earlier I assigned the parameter being passed to a variable, but in the private class if function i did not gave ==, I gave only =. But thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Arch is an argument not a method name. you cannot refer to the argument of function. refer to method name Runner instead called from RunTest.

Comment: How do I do that? Like this?    private TestResult RunTest(TCDetailInfo tcDetailInfo)

{if Runner.Arch="x64"

x=y+2;}

Comment: what do you want to achieve here. private TestResult RunTest(TCDetailInfo tcDetailInfo) { Runner("x64");}

Answer (score 0):

The problem was addressed by another, here my solution for that

```
public string Runner(string Arch = "x64") { //Do somthing; return Arch;}

private TestResult RunTest(TCDetailInfo tcDetailInfo)
{
  if (Runner())="x64"
    x=y+2;
}
```